# Error CloudPage

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

There is a problem with my code that is not answered by the individual.
If you implement this AMPSCRIPT if you access CloudPage, you will be able to dynamically activate the number you need to find error 500.

Do you know what is the solution ?

```
%%[
 
    SET @ Account_Number= QueryParameter('Account_Number')

    SET @SecondarioAccount = LookupRows("SecondarioAccount", "Account_Number", @Account_Number)
    IF RowCount(@SecondarioAccount) > 0 THEN
        SET @AccountData = Row(@SecondarioAccount, 1)
    ENDIF
]%%


    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        
       </style>

    <form action="https://cloud.email.xxxxxx.com" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="Account_Number" id="Account_Number" value="%%=v(@Account_Number)=%%">

    <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" required="" value="%%=v(RequestParameter('firstName'))=%%">

    <label for="lastName">Last Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" required="" value="%%=v(RequestParameter('lastName'))=%%">

    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required="" value="%%=v(RequestParameter('email'))=%%">

    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<br> 
%%[

    IF RequestParameter("submitted") == "true" THEN
        SET @FirstName = RequestParameter("firstName")
        SET @LastName = RequestParameter("lastName")
        SET @Email = RequestParameter("email")
        InsertData("AccountConvertiti", "FirstName", @FirstName, "LastName", @LastName, "Email", @Email, "Account_Number", @Account_Number)
    ENDIF
]%%
```

Comment: The specific question's a little hard to discern, but I'm guessing you're getting a 500 error when clicking on your submit button? Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be multiple issues with your code:

1. A space between @ and Account_Number in your first line of code.
2. `%%=v(RequestParameter('firstName'))=%%` is not the right way of printing a RequestParameter. You should just use `%%=RequestParameter('firstName')=%%`.

However, in this case, you probably would like to print the values retrieved in your LookupRows function. to do this, you will need the Field function, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="lastName" name="lastName" required="" value="%%=field(@AccountData,"lastName")=%%">
```